# What implementations of SMTP typically do with the mail data in response to RSET after DATA?

Tags: smtp, specifications, policy, lmtp

Here is what I gathered from the RFC 5321:

> 4.1.1.5.  RESET (RSET)
>
> This command specifies that the current mail transaction will be aborted. Any stored sender, recipients, *and mail data MUST be discarded,* and all buffers and state tables cleared.  The receiver MUST send a "250 OK" reply to a RSET command with no arguments.  A reset command may be issued by the client at any time. *It is effectively equivalent to a NOOP (i.e., it has no effect)* if issued immediately after EHLO, before EHLO is issued in the session, *after an end of data indicator has been sent and acknowledged*, or immediately before a QUIT.

The emphases are mine. This says that if we receive the RSET after the end of data indicator ".", but before we sent the acknowledgement, then we must discard the content of the message, which is currently being delivered. This does not seem practical. Moreover, the server can easily acts as if it received the RSET after he sent the acknowledgement - the client would not be able to know. Trying to know what is usually done, I found this discussion https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/ietf-smtp/current/msg00946.html where they say:

```
Under a RFC5321 compliant "No Quit/Mail" cancellation implementation, after
completing the DATA state, the server is waiting for a pending RSET, MAIL
or QUIT command:

    QUIT - complete transaction, if any
    MAIL - complete transaction, if any
          perform a "reset"
    RSET - cancel any pending DATA transaction delivery,
          perform a "reset"
    drop - cancel any pending DATA transaction delivery

We added this support in 2008 as a local policy option (EnableNoQuitCancel)
which will alter your SMTP state flow, your optimization and now you MUST 
follow RSET vs QUIT/MAIL correctly. RSET (after DATA) aborts the
transaction, QUIT/MAIL (after DATA) does not. RSET is not an NOOP at this 
point.
```

The specification says that discarding is a MUST. However, the above extract suggests that in practice it is interpreted as a MAY. I could look at the code of known implementations of SMTP/LMTP, such as Dovecot, but perhaps someone already reviewed that and this would save me time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text says "end of data indicator has been sent *and acknowledged"* which suggests that the client has received the server's response to the `DATA` command. Since the base protocol doesn't support command pipelining, I don't think sending anything after `DATA` but before the server's response (after the dot which terminates the `DATA` but before you receive a reply from the server) is well-defined behavior.

Personally, I can't think of any more reasonable server behavior than "pretend it didn't happen."

Comment: The question was about the server: whether the server should discard the mail data that it has received, started to deliver, but has not yet acknowledged. Yes, thinking in the name of the server, I plan to pretend that a RSET never happen before the acknowledgement. More importantly I intend to acknowledge before I start processing, because after it's not really in my hand anymore - I am just passing the data to a third party that I do not control.

Comment: I changed the wording slightly to make this perspective-neutral. I didn't even realize there was a bias towards the client; I meant a generic "you", so effectively passive voice, but I see now how that wasn't very clear. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: What does  "after the DATA command" mean? Often, it means after the 354 OK, returned just after DATA. In your answer, it must mean after the end of data indicator, the dot alone on a line. I agree, sending anything after the ".\r\n" , but before the acknowledgement, i.e. the reply, should not be seen as a well defined behavior. However, I suspect that, if it happens, it's not the client choice. There could be a transmission issue and a delay in the response and the client doesn't know what to do. So, it resets and tries again. If you can make your response less ambiguous, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here : https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1047 . They basically says that you can acknowledge before you start the processing and it is actually recommended to do so. This does not violate RFC 5321.  Of course, more information on this issue would be useful, but I am happy with rfc1047.